# Kendoui core file paths

Tags: jquery, html, kendo-ui, kendo-datepicker

I am trying out kendoui core datepicker but the provided examples don't work.

Kendoui's datepicker example gives file paths that don't exist

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.default.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css" />

<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
```

I have changed some of these to the correct paths but some files don't exist or are renamed in the download. This is what I have:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.common.core.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.default.min.css" />

<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/kendo.core.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/kendo.datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
```

What files are actually required get this working?

Comment: What do you mean the file path don't exist?

Comment: You want to use only DatePicker or all control ?

Answer (score 0):

Below JS is required for Kendo-DatePicker.

- jquery.js
- kendo.core.js
- kendo.calendar.js
- kendo.popup.js
- kendo.datepicker.js

For more information please check [kendo-UI documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/install/custom#datepicker) link.